# What is the verb for the action of creating a suggestion?

Tags: verbs

What is the verb for the action of creating a suggestion?

e.g. you have "raise a concern"

I don't like to go with "suggest a suggestion", but ok if thats the way to go.

Also, what is the correct term for these kind of verbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "to suggest something".

A good way to express what you're thinking of without using "suggest a suggestion" would be to go with "make a suggestion". It's the most common way of putting it.

Comment: Thanks. What about "offer an offer"? Also "make an offer"? How about "provide a suggestion"?

Comment: No problem mate. "Provide a suggestion" works just as well. It's a little less common and a tad more formal. But other than that, it's perfectly fine. Regarding your other question: "submit/make/place" an offer. They all work.

Comment: **offer** a suggestion is also quite common.

Answer (score 2):

**propose**, v. -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=propose&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

1. put forward (an idea or plan) for consideration or discussion by others.

   "he proposed a new nine-point peace plan"